# How to obtain minimum into the range when values >0?

Tags: excel-formula

I'm using this MINIFS formula on google sheet without problem

```
=MINIFS(D$2:D$1000;B$2:B$1000;J11)
```

but I need to obtain the minimum value into the range d$2:d$1000 excluding values <=0
so I tried different formulas like this

```
=MIN(IF(B$2:B$1000=J11,IF(D$2:D$1000>0,D$2:D$1000)))
```

that give me error :(

Comment: Please do not vandalize posted questions, including your own. Rolled back.

Comment: It's not *just* bad form and rude, it's also against the rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a criteria to the MINIFS:

```
=MINIFS(D$2:D$1000;B$2:B$1000;J11;D$2:D$1000;">0")
```

Comment: unfortunately this formula still give me 0 value :(